# How can i install Android Studio in Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: android-studio

I'm Not able to install Android Studio through Terminal, Please Suggest me right way to install Android Studio in Ubuntu 15.04 .

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:paolorotolo/android-studio
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install android-studio
```

Souce : https://paolorotolo.github.io/android-studio/